# xsl into xhtml by using template recursion

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i'm transforming all xml elements into xhtml `<div>` tags using a recursive template match.

basically, i wish to turn the element `name()` into a class name, ie . `<div class="name()">value</div>`

i used the following:

```
<body>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</body>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <div class="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

it works quite well, except it plucks out the values on parent tags. 
for example, this xml

```
  <TotalPayments>
    <Amount>26.96</Amount>
    <TaxableAmount>26.96</TaxableAmount>
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
    <ShippingAmount>0.00</ShippingAmount>
  </TotalPayments>
```

turns into:

```
<div class="TotalPayments">
        26.96
        26.96
        0.00
        0.00
  <div class="Amount">26.96</div>
  <div class="TaxableAmount">26.96</div>
  <div class="TaxAmount">0.00</div>
  <div class="ShippingAmount">0.00</div>
</div>
```

and i only want

```
<div class="TotalPayments">
  <div class="Amount">26.96</div>
  <div class="TaxableAmount">26.96</div>
  <div class="TaxAmount">0.00</div>
  <div class="ShippingAmount">0.00</div>
</div>
```

And it gets worse and worse up the tree. the root has all that too.

so should i do a test or can one select only certain types.
i also tried matching

```
* | text()
* | node()
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` and then change the `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. That way the default template for text node children will output them (and the elements children are processed the same as before).

Comment: fabulous. works perfectly.
so this default template (for text node children) is hidden somewhere.